# How do I create a JavaFX Node B that has exactly the same graphical representation as another Node A without doubling the memory footprint?

Tags: java, graphics, javafx

My team is parsing a file that specifies a graphical element and then clones that graphic to show in many other spatial positions. One file reaches an [OutOfMemoryError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) due to its extensive use of clones. I have not yet discovered a mechanism in JavaFX to duplicate visuals to appear multiple times in the scene graph without each Node having the same memory footprint. These are vector graphics, not images, and we are primarily using [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Path.html) nodes.

Please help find a memory efficient way to replicate vector graphics on the screen, where each clone may have arbitrary transforms not shared by the other clones, and guarding against potential pixelation where a clone may be scaled up. I have contrived the following brief example of the problem, which, on my computer, fails after roughly 60 seconds on first run (15 after warm-up) using Xmx512m. Raising Xmx is a natural suggestion, but not an answer to the question.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.PathElement;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * An example of running out of memory by duplicating a complicated vector graphic.
 */
public class ReplicateVectorGraphic extends Application {

    private Pane drawingBoard;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        drawingBoard = new Pane();
        Button runUntilOOME = new Button("run until OOME");
        runUntilOOME.setOnAction( this::generateGraphics );
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(drawingBoard, runUntilOOME, null, null, null);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creates new nodes based on the graphics in the simulated (pseudorandom)
     * file until we run out of memory.
     *
     * @param ae
     *            An ignored event that kicked off the operation.
     */
    private void generateGraphics(ActionEvent ae) {
        int n = 0;
        Instant begin = Instant.now();
        try {
            Group completeGraphic = new Group();
            // Hitting 32k clones would be success. (YMMV, but bear in mind
            // arbitrary end-user hardware. also check your Xmx.)
            for (;n <Short.MAX_VALUE; n++) {
                Path p = new Path();
                // load data from the simulated file
                populatePath(p);
                completeGraphic.getChildren().add( p );
            }
            drawingBoard.getChildren().add( completeGraphic );
            new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "32k graphics displayed!").show();
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError oome) {
            final int nbr = n;
            Platform.runLater( () -> displayAlert(nbr, ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between( begin, Instant.now())) );
        }
    }

    private static void displayAlert(long nbr, long seconds) {
        String m = "Cloned graphic "+nbr+" times in "+ seconds +" seconds.";
        Alert a = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR, m);
        a.setTitle( "OOME Alert" );
        a.show();
    }

    private static void populatePath(Path p) {
        // in lieu of a real graphic to load, we'll generate a
        // pseudorandom sequence of points that will be the same each time
        Random r = new Random(42);
        ObservableList<PathElement> pathElements = p.getElements();
        pathElements.add( new MoveTo(r.nextDouble(), r.nextDouble()) );
        // 2048 elements is a reasonable amount of detail for a vector graphic.
        // reducing the detail of the graphic is not an option. we have to load what we're given.
        for (int i=0; i<2048; i++) {
            pathElements.add( new LineTo(r.nextDouble(), r.nextDouble()) );
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This code is also a [bitbucket snippet](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/travisfw/L8pG4). I would welcome commits on bitbucket as well.

Comment: Could the path be converted to an image, or does it need to be represented as path, as there are interactions on it?

Comment: @hotzst if you have a method to do this by converting to an image, and can avoid pixellation (including blurriness from upsampling) in cases where clones have scaling transforms, I would love to see it!

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to nodes, which may only appear once in a scene graph, you can freely re-use the path elements of a path. So there is no need for duplication there which should save you some space.

I also don't understand why you increment "n" twice in your code.

Comment: Thanks for catching the extra n++. I haven't tried reusing path elements. That may help. Each Path still would have a new Collection, but perhaps that's insignificant enough. Ideally the solution could work for all shapes and nodes, which our software may need to support at some point.